# How can Ruby 1.8.7 and the Savon 1.20 Client ignore the message that self signed cert was used in the transaction

Tags: ruby, ssl, savon

We are using Ruby 1.8.7 and Savon 1.2 to connect to a server SOAP webservice.  The code is as below:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do | wsdl, http, wsse |
    wsdl.endpoint = @exportsURL
    wsdl.namespace = @exportsURL
    http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none
    http.auth.basic @appUsername, @appPassword
    #wsdl.raise_errors = false
end
```

As you can see, we have turned off http.auth.ssl.verify_mode.

Even so, I always see "at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain".

I understand how the PKI works and would like to use a self signed certificate on the server.  However, we would like to ignore the message "at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain" on the console out.

Could you suggest a way to ignore the output?